# How to prevent document scrolling in mobile while using jQuery touch punch

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mobile

I have a case where I have a draggable resizable div (cropper) over an image.  In order to get touch to work on mobile I imported the jQuery touch punch plugin.  The issue is that while moving the draggable around the page wants to scroll.  I mocked up an example.  The following code fixes my scroll to the correct position.  This works on the PC but not an android phone.

```
        $("#drag").draggable({
                containment : "parent"
        });

        $("#drag").resizable({
            handles: {
                'ne': '#negrip',
                'se': '#segrip',
                'sw': '#swgrip',
                'nw': '#nwgrip'
            }
        });

$("#noScroll").click(function (e) {
        $("body").addClass("stop-scrolling");
        $(document).scroll(function(e) { $(this).scrollTop(1000);});
        $(document).bind('touchstart', function(e){e.preventDefault()});
        $(document).bind('touchmove', function(e){e.preventDefault()});    
});
```

```
<body>

<div style="height: 500px; border : 1px solid;">big div</div>       
<a id="noScroll">STOP SCROLLING</a>
        <span id="holder">
                        <span id="drag">
                            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" id="nwgrip"></div>
                            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" id="negrip"></div>
                            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" id="swgrip"></div>
                            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se" id="segrip"></div>
                        </span>
                        <img id="img" src="http://halo.bungie.org/misc/assaultgodzilla_japanhalo2/lg/06_call_of_spartans.jpg" />
                </span>
</body>
```

SEPERATOR

```
        #holder { height:300px; width:300px; border:1px solid; display:block; position: relative; overflow:hidden; margin: 0 auto; }
        #img { height:1000px; width:1000px; display: block; background: no-repeat; overflow: hidden; }
        #drag { height:100px; width:100px; border: 1px solid #000000; background: #FFFFFF; display: block; position:absolute; top:0px; z-index:33; opacity:.6; }
  .stop-scrolling { height:100%; overflow:hidden; }


        #nwgrip, #negrip, #swgrip, #segrip, #ngrip, #egrip, #sgrip, #wgrip {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid #000000;
        }

        #nwgrip { top: 0; left: 0; }
        #negrip { top: 0; right: 0; }
        #segrip { bottom: 0; right: 0; }
        #swgrip { bottom: 0; left: 0; }
```

On the phone zoom slightly, scroll to the bottom, and click stop scroll.  Now drag the small box around and you will notice that the page tries to scroll if you bring it to the top kind of fast.

A link to the fiddle and direct js shell link is:

http://jsfiddle.net/jMtjC/3/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/jMtjC/3/show/

Go to the js shell link on mobile.  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Exactly my question today. Did you find a solution by now?